# dotnet build produces "error NU1403: The package Libuv.1.9.1 sha512 validation failed"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

This error is straightforward enough... but the trouble is that I can't for the life of me find any reference to this package in my solution so I can't update or remove the reference. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: The package is indirectly referenced by others. You might clean up your local caches and then restore again, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders

Comment: It was a nice idea but alas didn't quite do the trick. I should mention that this is only happening on my build server, but not locally. I'm going to try to track down which package is referencing the problematic one and she if that can help at all...

Comment: Hi @christok, did you find any solutions for this? I'm having exact same issue with my colleagues. With my hashes their builds do not work and other way around. However, what is interesting is that our build server manages to build the application with both hashes without any errors.

Worth noting that we are having issues with other packages like runtime.opensuse.13.2-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.4.3.0 and System.ComponentModel.Primitives.4.3.0 + some others.